# Is there a way to get a hash out of an Apollo request

Tags: graphql, cryptography, apollo-client, react-apollo, hmac

After trying for hours to try implementing a Hmac token on a react Apollo client request, I just couldn't find a way to retrieve the final request body that is being sent.

Is there a way to get the request body sent to the server before the client sends it or no way at all ? Not being able to get body hash causes for some security concerns for Mitm attacks since using a jwt the way Apollo docs show it doesn't provide with a way of signing the content.

Comment: @xadm willSendResponse is an ApolloServer feature and doesn't allow to sign client request.

Comment: for client use 'links'

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/ ... https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client - could be an inspiration as end/terminating link

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994971/how-to-add-hmac-in-grapqhl-queries-from-client), I came up with something

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  concat,
  useQuery,
  gql,
} from "@apollo/client";
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";
import { print } from "graphql/language/printer";

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:3000/dev/query" });

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  const { query, variables, operationName } = operation,
    payload = {
      variables,
      operationName,
      query: print(query),
    };
  console.log(payload);
  // custom headers
  const token = getAuthHeader(payload, "key"), // create HMAC here
    headers = {
      hmac: token,
    };
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
    },
  });
  return forward(operation);
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: false, //quite important
  }),
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
});

function getAuthHeader(payload_string, sk) {
  var str = JSON.stringify(payload_string);
  console.log(str);
  var hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(str, sk).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
  return hmac;
}
function MakeRequest() {
  const request = `
    query {
      items {
          _id
      
      }
    }
  `;
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(gql(request));

  //Whatever you wanna do with it.
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MakeRequest />
    </div>
  );
}

render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Seems to work correctly.